# Creating tables and importing data from .sql files in Spring boot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Current apporach:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=<name>.sql 
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
```

Not sure what am I missing, and why in this configuration, the .sql files are not executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

We can use

```
spring.datasource.schema= # Schema (DDL) script resource references.
spring.datasource.data= # Data (DML) script resource references.
```

- No need to change the SQL filenames
- Can Keep schema generation and insertion in the same file
- Can specify multiple files

  `spring.datasource.schema = classpath:/abc.sql,classpath:/abc2.sql`

***NOTE:***

- For schema generation and insertion in the same file do not use `spring.datasource.data`, we have to use `spring.datasource.schema`
- Keep all files in *src/main/resources*
- set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

---

**Initial Answer**

Spring boot already configures Hibernate to create your schema based on your entities. To create it using SQL (in *src/main/resources*) files set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

---

Create schema.sql (to create the table) and data.sql (to insert the records) in *src/main/resources*

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    id   INTEGER      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('India');
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Brazil');
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('USA');
INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('Italy');
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

---

Comment: is there a way to do it without renaming the files to be data.sql and schema.sql. In fact I' ve data and schemas in one file. In other words, is it possible to make it worksin such condiitons: other name than you specified and with mixed schemas and data in one .sql file?

Comment: Hello, @Schroedinger I have updated the answer, please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful to you