# data.sql with spring boot JPA Postresql is not loading

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have written a spring boot application. I want to setup initial database data with a data.sql file.

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

src/main/java/package_name/model/my_entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_entry")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String userId;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<SongList> songLists;

    public User() {
    }
    ...
}
```

src/main/resources/data.sql

```
insert into user_entry (user_id, first_name, last_name, password) values
('MaMu', 'Maxime', 'Muster', 'pass1234');
```

However the data appears not to be loaded into the database during deployment.

edit:

adding `spring.datasource.data= classpath:/data.sql` in my src/main/resources/application.properties solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have these properties to create and insert the records into a table. As you only need to insert the records you can avoid `spring.datasource.schema`

```
spring.datasource.schema= # Schema (DDL) script resource references.
spring.datasource.data= # Data (DML) script resource references.
```

Set SQL file

```
spring.datasource.data= classpath:/data.sql
```

**Notes:**

- For schema generation and insertion in the same file do not use `spring.datasource.data`, we have to use `spring.datasource.schema`
- Keep all files in *src/main/resources*
- set `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`
- Also make sure you don't have used `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` as it will set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` behind scenes and will invalidate `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: For more details, you may explore https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528481/10961238

Comment: Hey thanks. that totally worked for me.
Another problem was the using of double quotes instead of single quotes in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

In case your Entity not getting considered add below annotation on your Springboot main class just below your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation,

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"package_name.model.my_entity"}
```

Also, after removing `@Id` tag from Entity and it was working for me (Not sure it can be the reason).

Comment: sorry but this version made my whole application crash on startup